# Convert Dstream to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

So, here my aim is to take input from kafka topic and convert it to dataframe and finally putting it to Elasticsearch. Here the problem is with while converting Dstream to DF, it is showing error.

Example:

> ```
>                   ________________________
>                   |_first_name_|_last_name_|
> abhijeet,kumar => | abhijeet   |  kumar    |
>                    -----------------------
> ```

"abhijeet,kumar" is the input to kafka topic and will be converted to df.

```
case class employee(first_name: String, last_name: String)

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(batchIntervalSeconds))

    val wordStream = kafkaConsumeStream(ssc)

    wordStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      val partitioned_rdd = rdd.map(line => line.toString.split(",").map(_.trim))
      val df = partitioned_rdd.map{case Array(s0, s1) => employee(s0, s1)}.toDF

      df.show

      import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
      df.saveToEs("kafkawordcount_v1/kwc")
    }
```

But this is not working and throwing error:

```
18/07/16 01:08:11 ERROR Utils: Exception encountered
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(DStreamGraph.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.writeObject(DStreamGraph.scala:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(DStream.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStream.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(DStream.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.writeObject(DStream.scala:512)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializableWithWriteObjectMethod(SerializationDebugger.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitArray(SerializationDebugger.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializableWithWriteObjectMethod(SerializationDebugger.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
    at main.scala.com.sntz.spark.streaming.KafkaES$.main(KafkaES.scala:83)
    at main.scala.com.sntz.spark.streaming.KafkaES.main(KafkaES.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:93)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:87)
    at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:65)
    at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:77)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you tried using Structured Streaming instead? Your error is because you're making a SQLContext within the foreach but using the outer SparkContext

Comment: Also, FWIW, you should check out Kafka Connect Elasticsearch connector

Comment: Ok thanks the problem is now solved by defining SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf) inside foreachRDD

Comment: Can you tell me the reason behind this @cricket_007

Comment: The reason is in your error. The SparkContext is not serializable, so you must get a new one within the closure